# How does scoping work with JavaScript includes?

Tags: javascript

For example suppose I have the following within my HTML

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The script defines a variable named socket.  Immediately below I have the following

```
<script src="/javascripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Within script.js I try to access socket and get a not defined error.  However if I use an inline script I can access the variable.  How can I access 'socket' from within script.js?

Comment: You're trying to access the variable when the socket-script hasn't loaded yet. Use `$(document).ready()` or something.

Comment: What is the code for `socket.io.js`?

Comment: If this is socket.io, it exports a variable called `io`, but not one called socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have "includes", per se.

Any variable declared at the top level of a JS file will be available in *global scope* immediately after the file is loaded, i.e. at the point the `<script>` tag is used.

Note that scripts loaded with the `defer` attribute on the `<script>` tag may not be loaded immediately, and so any variables declared therein will  not be available immediately.

Variables declared with the `var` keyword *inside* a callback function *do not* appear in the global scope.  So in this code:

```
var a = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = 1;
});
```

`a` will be in the global scope, but `b` will not.

Whereas in this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    c = 1;
});
```

`c` *will* be in global scope (as it was not declared with the `var` keyword) but *not until the callback function has been invoked*.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining these scripts? Are they on the head tag? If so, you should be able to access variables between scripts...